# ¿No puedo instalar Docker ToolBox en Windows 10 Home?

Tags: windows, docker, windows10, docker-compose, docker-machine

Un compañero en el trabajo me pidió que instale Docker para hacer proyectos con laravel. Debido a que mi windows es home, no puedo instalarlo, pero si sugirió Docker toolbox ya que aparentemente ese está hecho para que sirva en windows 10.

Entre al menu de BIOS para habilitar la virtualización, desinstale VirtualBox para que se instale el que viene con Docker, descargué, instalé y...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El git bash está ahí porque estoy siguiendo este tutorial: https://dev.to/aschmelyun/the-beauty-of-docker-for-local-laravel-development-13c0

Para hacer proyectos laravel.

¿Alguien sabe como solucionar esto?

Comment: pareciera que no te reconoce la activación en la BIOS, podrías revisarla para estar seguro que guardaste los cambios de la BIOS, y ademas si puedes colocar el modelo procesador que tiene tu computadora para verificar que posea la opción.

Comment: Ademas desde windows 10 ya existe la opción nativa de docker, pero tienes que tener windows 10 profesional para activar HYPER-V el problema que evita que funcione VMWare y VirtualBOX(Este ultimo con la nueva versión ya tiene una opción de compatibilidad acambio de perder rendimiento) por el Hipervisor de microsoft administra toda la virtualizacion.

Comment: Investigando un poco parece que windows 10 Home suele dar ese problema a la hora de validar VT-X con docker toolbox, ve a la carpeta de docker toolbox y ejecuta `docker-machine create default --virtualbox-no-vtx-check` para evitar la comprobación